# Como guardar un pdf generado por dompdf en una carpeta especifica en mi servidor

Tags: php, dompdf

Buenas tengo unos documentos creados por dompdf pero cuando creo el doc. siempre me sale guardar en la ultima carpeta donde guardo algo pero quiero darle una ruta especifica para que guarde intente con file_put_contents pero aun asi me sigue saliendo la ultima ruta osea no hace caso talves estoy en algun error adjunto codigo:

```
 $codigoHTML=utf8_encode($codigoHTML);
 $dompdf=new DOMPDF();
 $dompdf->load_html($codigoHTML);
 ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
 $dompdf->render();
 $output = $dompdf->output();
 $namepdf = "GAR".$id.".pdf";
 $path = '../../PDFDOC/'.$namepdf;
 $dompdf->stream($namepdf);
 file_put_contents($path, $output);
```

Es la ruta donde quiero guardar el pdf pero sale el lugar donde guardar posiblemente tenga un error o estoy haciendo algo mal cualquier ayuda o sugerencia estare muy agradecido.
Gracias

Comment: Hola DAVE, en lo personal prefiero usar FPDF por su sencillez con lo amigable que es con el backend, creo que en DOMPdf usa una funcion llamada `output()`, asegurate de usarla al momento de guardar el archivo en tu funcion `file_put_contents`

Comment: Hola Ruben intente con el output(), como sugeriste pero sin ningun exito edite mi pregunta para q puedas verlo talves estoy haciendo algo mal.

Comment: De donde surge la variable $id? Puedes hacer el output después del stream?

Comment: Prueba a quitar esta línea: `$dompdf->stream($namepdf);`, te está pidiendo que indiques la carpeta dónde se descargará el PDF porque `stream` fuerza una descarga del archivo, no lo necesitas si no quieres descargarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias ya solucione el problema el codigo quedo asi:

```
$codigoHTML=utf8_encode($codigoHTML);
$dompdf=new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($codigoHTML);
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
$namepdf = "GAR".$id.".pdf";
$path = '../../PDFDOC/'.$namepdf;
file_put_contents($path, $output);
```

Con eso directamente exporta a una carpeta especifica en el servidor.
Muchas gracias